# Make an action after two events happened - JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Want to change submit button color after email verification and checkbox marked. Added listeners on changes and they work well. But have no idea how to find out when this events are going to happen to launch function what is going to change submit button color.

````
```
https://jsfiddle.net/nvologdins/brfj2xk1/
```
````

Comment: Note that they can also uncheck the box or make their email invalid again. Ideally listen for both events, and then you can set your global variables to true, but also make sure to set to false if not valid. Then finally for either event, call a function which would check whether both are true or not, then toggle the submit button color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how to do this.

I also changed the logic a bit to update the values if the user changes them again. - @Ultimater mentioned this also.

```js
function setupButton() {
  if (validEmail && validCheckbox) {
    // add/show/enable submit button or simply change the color
    button.style.color = "red";
  } else {
    // remove/hide/disable submit button revert the changes
    button.style.color = "";
  }
}
form.input.addEventListener('input', (event)=>{
  validEmail = emailRegex.test(event.target.value);
  setupButton();
})
form.checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
  validCheckbox = event.target.checked;
  setupButton();
})
```

I would also suggest a different method to validate the form using the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation).

Every element has a validity check which can easily be accessed on the form element using [`formElement.checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#the_constraint_validation_api) and returns true/false if all (required) fields inside the form are filled with valid values.

```html
<form oninput="this.querySelector('#submitButton').disabled = !this.checkValidity();" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); console.log('Submit prevented but the form seems to be valid.'); return false;">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="newslettermail">E-Mail</label>
    <!-- you could also define a more specific pattern on the email input since email would allow foo@bar as valid mail -->
    <input type="email" id="newslettermail" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="newsletterAcceptTos" required>
    <label for="newsletterAcceptTos">I accept the Terms of Service</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="textFieldWithPattern">Enter <strong>foo</strong> or <strong>bar</strong></label>
    <input type="text" id="textFieldWithPattern" pattern="^(foo|bar)$" required>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" id="submitButton" disabled>Submit</button>
  <button type="submit">Force submit (will show errors on invalid input)</button>
</form>
```

Using this, the browser for itself checks the values if they contain a valid value.

- An `input[type=email]` with required flag must contain a valid mail address.
- A checkbox with required flag, must be checked.
- An `input` with required and a pattern must contain a value matching the regular expression from the pattern-attribute.

Comment: His code does contain a submit button. Just he didn't put a value inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create extra variables and listen on two form elements separately... You can check the whole thing and update accordingly only by listening to the `form` element

```js
let form = document.querySelector('form');
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
let submit = document.getElementById('button');

const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

form.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (checkbox.checked && emailRegex.test(input.value)) {
    submit.style.color = "red";
  } else {
    submit.style.color = "black"
  }
})

//Update
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const changeEvent = new Event('change');
  form.dispatchEvent(changeEvent)
})
```

```html
<form class="main__emailAndTerms emailAndTerms">
  <div class="emailAndTerms__email">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Type your email address here...">
    <label class="emailAndTerms__terms">I agree to <a href="#"><span class="terms__link">terms of service</span></a>
                <input type="checkbox" class="terms__checkbox" id="checkbox">
                <span class="terms__checkbox_custom"></span>
            </label>
    <button type="submit" class="email__submitButton" id="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This will fail if you check the TOS thing first, then fill the mail and press enter. You need the input event.

Comment: The change event is valid for both, but they need to first unfocus the text field. Although red is generally used to indicate a problem. It will confuse users if that's the color you're using to indicate valid.

Comment: @Ultimater Have updated my code, now it works as you change input.